# How to make wro4j-maven-plugin fail the build when a preprocessor fails?

Tags: maven, less

I am using the `wro4j-maven-plugin` for preprocessing my `.js`, `.css` and `.less` resources.

When a preprocessor fails, like when a `.less` file contains a syntax error, the plugin just outputs a stacktrace in the build and keeps on building.

This results in having to monitor the build process, or risk having broken resources. Is there any way to make this plugin `failOnError` like one would do with an `AntRun`?

pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>ro.isdc.wro4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>wro4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.5</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>compile</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <minimize>true</minimize>
        <jsDestinationFolder>${basedir}/WebContent/resources/min/js/</jsDestinationFolder>
        <cssDestinationFolder>${basedir}/WebContent/resources/min/css/</cssDestinationFolder>
        <contextFolder>${basedir}/WebContent/</contextFolder>
        <wroFile>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/wro.xml</wroFile>
        <extraConfigFile>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/wro.properties</extraConfigFile>
        <ignoreMissingResources>false</ignoreMissingResources>
        <wroManagerFactory>ro.isdc.wro.maven.plugin.manager.factory.ConfigurableWroManagerFactory</wroManagerFactory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

wro.properties:

```
preProcessors=cssUrlRewriting,cssImport,yuiJsMin
postProcessors=lessCss,yuiCssMin
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default behavior of the lessCss processor when an exception occurs is to abort the processing and leave the resource unchanged. The reasoning behind this is that when a valid css is processed with lessCss, it may fail because it has invalid syntax from Less point of view. This usually happens when you process mixed resources (css & less).

The next wro4j version (1.4.7) will change the default behavior when dealing with exceptions during resource proccessing. Thus, when an exception will occur - the overall processing will fail (it will be possible to configure this behavior).

There is a workaround for earlier versions (including 1.4.5). You can extend the LessCssProcessor and override the onException method. Example:

```
/**
 * Invoked when a processing exception occurs.
 */
protected void onException(final WroRuntimeException e) {
   throw e;
}
```

By using this new processor instead, your build will fail anytime the processor will fail.